# If a husband or wife medically die but are resuscitated, is a new kiddushin required?

Tags: halacha, death, medicine, kiddushin-eirusin

If a husband or wife is on an operating table and is pronounced clinically dead, but then a couple minutes later is miraculously resuscitated ([example](https://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/317645.php)):

- Would this couple require a new kiddushin?

**NOTE:** this question is only applicable to those that hold clinical death is considered death (see this [article on "Brain Death"](https://www.koltorah.org/halachah//brain-death-by-rabbi-howard-jachter) by R' Chaim Jachter)

Comment: I would say that the declaration that he is dead would be treated as a mistake as we see that he is alive in front of us.

Comment: The Ben Ish Chai (Ben Yoyada) explains that Reb Zeirah did not need to do,kiddushin his proof is from har sinai that all of KY nesahmos left yet no Kidushin was necessary